# 2d array in Struct - C -

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Im trying to assign a array to my letter.charData but i get this error:

IntelliSense: expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Im trying to add my array arr to letter.charData

Thanks in advance!

```
struct _Letter{
    char character;
    int width;
    int charData[8][5];
};

typedef struct _Letter Letter;

Letter *allocLetter(void)
{
    Letter *letter;

    letter = (Letter*) malloc(1 * sizeof(Letter));

    letter->character = NULL;
    letter->width = NULL;

    /* charData? */

    return letter;
}

int main(void)
{ 
    Letter letter = *allocLetter();

    int arr[8][5] = 
    {
        0,0,0,0,0,
        1,0,0,0,0,
        1,0,0,0,0,
        1,0,0,0,0,
        1,0,0,0,0,
        1,0,0,0,0,
        1,0,0,0,0,
        1,0,0,0,0
    };

    letter.character = '1';
    letter.charData = arr;

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think `_L...` is reserved. Name it `Letter_` or something.

Comment: why don't you instead pass arr to the allocLetter together with the character e.g. Letter* allocLetter( int **arr, char ch ) and then initialize it in there by copying it into the struct.

Answer (score 5):

`_Letter::charData` is an array, not a pointer, so you can't just assign another array to it. Either copy `arr`'s contents into it with `memcpy`, or change its type to a pointer:

```
typedef struct {
    char character;
    int width;
    int (*charData)[5];
} Letter;
```

Also,

1. Identifier names shouldn't start with `_` followed by a capital
2. `NULL` should only be used for pointers; use `'\0'` for characters, plain `0` for integers
3. You don't check the return value of `malloc` for null
4. You're not freeing allocated memory.